# Cox model with Lasso for PH test and P value

Tags: lasso, model, cox-model

I am using the `penalized` package in r for fitting a Cox model with a lasso penalty.

Does the Cox model + lasso need to test proportionality?

How do you get the p-value for the nonzero coefficients in the model?

Thanks for any response.